# How can I enter a date into an excel cell with a double click but have it only effect empty cells

Tags: vba, excel

So I currently have a worksheet with multiple cells filled with formulas, but I use a double click function to fill specific cells with todays date. This works for me becuase I made the workbook but I am going to send this book out and I want to make sure that others working on it dont accidentally over write a formula with todays by double clicking on it.  So my thought is to build into the macro an if then statement to check if the cell already has data in it.  Unfortunatly I cant get it to work.

My current code is

```
Private Sub WorkSheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Target = Date
Cancel = True
End Sub
```

My attempt is

```
Private Sub WorkSheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Target Is Nothing Then
Cancel = True
Target = Date
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace `If Target Is Nothing` with `If IsEmpty(Target) Then`

Answer (score 1):

A non-macro approach as an alternative:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+`:`, <kbd>Enter</kbd> in first empty cell (say A1).
Select range.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+`g`, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+`s`, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+`k`, <kbd>OK</kbd>
`=A1`, <kbd>F4</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.